# How do I use angularjs to send a http PUT Request using an id

Tags: python, angularjs, http, cors, put

I have developed a Restful API in python that works with my database and table called groups. I have created script which allows me to GET & POST and I want to create script for PUT that will update a group. On my html document when you click on a group it populates the groups details on a form. On this form you should make any changes you need and then the script will use the group_id to send a PUT request to my server and store the update into  my database.

groups.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Groups</title>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Players</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Team</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Manager</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">Stadiums</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Matches</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Leaderboards</a> </li>
  <li><a href="">Groups</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="row" ng-app = "app" ng-controller = "getGroups">
    <div class="column" >
        <h1>View Groups</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Group ID</th>
            <th>Group Name</th>
            <th>Team A</th>
            <th>Team B</th>
            <th>Team C</th>
            <th>Team D</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody ng-repeat = "groups in allGroups">
            <tr ng-repeat = "item in groups">
                <td ng-bind = "item.group_id"></td>
                <td ng-bind = "item.group_name"></td>
                <td ng-bind = "item.team_a"></td>
                <td ng-bind = "item.team_b"></td>
                <td ng-bind = "item.team_c"></td>
                <td ng-bind = "item.team_d"></td>
                <td><button ng-click="">Select Group</button></td>
                <td><button ng-click = "deleteGroup(item.group_id)">Delete Group</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
        </div>
<div class="column">
    <h1>Add New Group</h1>
    <form name = "addGroup" ng-submit = "submit()">
        <label>Group Name: </label><input type = "text" name = "Group Name" ng-model = "form.group_name"><br>
        <label>Team A: </label><input type = "text" name = "Team A" ng-model = "form.team_a"><br>
        <label>Team B: </label><input type = "text" name = "Team B" ng-model = "form.team_b"><br>
        <label>Team C: </label><input type = "text" name = "Team C" ng-model = "form.team_c"><br>
        <label>Team D: </label><input type = "text" name = "Team D" ng-model = "form.team_d"><br>
        <input type = "submit" value="Add New Group">
    </form>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <h1>Update Group</h1>
        <form class="data-form" name="updateGroup" ng-submit="updateGroups(update.group_id)">
            <label>Group ID</label><input type="text" name="Group ID" ng-model="update.group_id" readonly><br>
            <label>Group Name: </label><input type = "text" name = "Group Name" ng-model = "update.group_name"><br>
            <label>Team A: </label><input type = "text" name = "Team A" ng-model = "update.team_a"><br>
            <label>Team B: </label><input type = "text" name = "Team B" ng-model = "update.team_b"><br>
            <label>Team C: </label><input type = "text" name = "Team C" ng-model = "update.team_c"><br>
            <label>Team D: </label><input type = "text" name = "Team D" ng-model = "update.team_d"><br>
            <input type = "submit" value="Update Group">
        </form>

    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('app',[]);

    app.controller('getGroups', function($scope, $http)
    {
        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/groups"
        }).then(function onSuccess(response) {
            $scope.allGroups = response.data;
        }, function error(response) {
            $scope.allGroups = response.statusText;
            alert("Something went wrong: Error No. 1")
        });

        $scope.submit = function()
        {
            $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/groups",
                data: $scope.form,
                headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' }
            }).then(function onSuccess(response) {
                alert("Group has been added");
            }, function error() {
                alert("Something has gone wrong: Error No. 2");
            });
        };

        $scope.updateGroups = function(id)
        {
            $http({
                method: "PUT",
                url: ("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/groups/" + id),
                data: $scope.form,
            }).then(function onSuccess(response) {
                alert("Group has been added");
            }, function error() {
                alert("Opps")
            });
        };

        $scope.deleteGroup = function(id)
        {
            $http({
                method: "DELETE",
                url: ("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/groups/" + id),
            }).then(function onSuccess() {
                alert("Group has been deleted");
            }, function error() {
                alert("Something went wrong: Error No. 3");
            });
        };
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("td", this).on("click", function () {
            var tds = $(this).parents("tr").find("td");
            $.each(tds, function (i, v) {
                $($(".data-form input")[i]).val($(v).text());
            });

        });

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It is my $scope.updateGroups im having issue with, It should accept the id from the form and use that to store the updated details in the database

```
<form class="data-form" name="updateGroup" ng-submit="updateGroups(update.group_id)">
            <label>Group ID</label><input type="text" name="Group ID" ng-model="update.group_id" readonly><br>
            <label>Group Name: </label><input type = "text" name = "Group Name" ng-model = "update.group_name"><br>
            <label>Team A: </label><input type = "text" name = "Team A" ng-model = "update.team_a"><br>
            <label>Team B: </label><input type = "text" name = "Team B" ng-model = "update.team_b"><br>
            <label>Team C: </label><input type = "text" name = "Team C" ng-model = "update.team_c"><br>
            <label>Team D: </label><input type = "text" name = "Team D" ng-model = "update.team_d"><br>
            <input type = "submit" value="Update Group">
        </form>
```

And this is the function Im struggling to get working:

```
$scope.updateGroups = function(id)
        {
            $http({
                method: "PUT",
                url: ("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/groups/" + id),
                data: $scope.form,
            }).then(function onSuccess(response) {
                alert("Group has been added");
            }, function error() {
                alert("Opps")
            });
        };
```

I feel like im making a small error somewhere

---

> VM201:1 OPTIONS 127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/groups/undefined 404 (NOT FOUND)

I had an issue with CORS but I added code to my API - def after_request(response):

```
response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*') 
response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Authorization') 
response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS')
return response
```

Im getting this error in the console as well

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at `'127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/groups/undefined'` from origin `'localhost:63342'` has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

But my GET, POST and DELETE are working as they should

My response headers are

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Which I assumed should allow the PUT request to go through. But im getting a 404 error and the url is `127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/groups/undefined` which the `undefined` should be an `id` that is passed through the form.

My API.py file which contains my routes

```
# Import statements
import mysql.connector
from flask import Flask, abort, jsonify, request

# Global Constants
VERSION = 'v1'
BASE_URI = '/api/' + VERSION
GROUPS = '/groups'
GROUP = '/group'
URI_FOR_ALL_GROUPS = BASE_URI + GROUPS
MYSQL_USER = 'root'
MYSQL_PASS = ''
MYSQL_HOST = 'localhost'
MYSQL_DB = 'football'

# Creating an instance of Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


def create_connection():  # Method to Create Connection to Database
    return mysql.connector.connect(user=MYSQL_USER,
                                   password=MYSQL_PASS,
                                   host=MYSQL_HOST,
                                   database=MYSQL_DB)


# POST: Adding a new Group
@app.route(URI_FOR_ALL_GROUPS, methods=['POST'])
def add_group():
    # Method to add Group
    if not request.json:
        abort(400)
    conn = create_connection()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    query = "INSERT INTO groups(group_name, team_a," \
            "team_b, team_c, team_d)" \
            "values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    cursor.execute(query, (request.json['group_name'],
                           request.json['team_a'],
                           request.json['team_b'],
                           request.json['team_c'],
                           request.json['team_d']))
    id = cursor.lastrowid
    conn.commit()
    query = "SELECT * FROM groups WHERE group_id=" + str(id)
    cursor.execute(query)
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    group = {}
    for (key, value) in zip(cursor.description, row):
        group[key[0]] = value
    conn.close()

    return jsonify(group), 201


# GET: Get a single groups information
@app.route(URI_FOR_ALL_GROUPS + '/<int:id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_group(id):
    # Method to retrieve the information of a single group
    conn = create_connection()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    query = "SELECT * FROM groups WHERE group_id=" + str(id)
    cursor.execute(query)
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    group = {}
    for (key, value) in zip(cursor.description, row):
        group[key[0]] = value
    conn.close()

    return jsonify(group), 200


# GET Retrieve all the groups
@app.route(URI_FOR_ALL_GROUPS, methods=['GET'])
def get_groups():
    # Method to retrieve all groups
    conn = create_connection()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    query = "SELECT * FROM groups"
    cursor.execute(query)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    groups = []
    for row in rows:
        dict = {}
        for (key, value) in zip(cursor.description, row):
            dict[key[0]] = value
        groups.append(dict)
    conn.close()

    return jsonify({'groups': groups}), 200


# PUT: Updating a group
@app.route(URI_FOR_ALL_GROUPS + '/<int:id>', methods=['PUT'])
def update_group(id):
    # Method to update a group
    conn = create_connection()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    query = "UPDATE groups SET group_name=%s, team_a=%s," \
            "team_b=%s, team_c=%s, team_d=%s " \
            "WHERE group_id=%s"
    cursor.execute(query, (request.json['group_name'],
                           request.json['team_a'],
                           request.json['team_b'],
                           request.json['team_c'],
                           request.json['team_d'], id))
    conn.commit()
    query = "SELECT * FROM groups WHERE group_id=" + str(id)
    cursor.execute(query)
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    group = {}
    for (key, value) in zip(cursor.description, row):
        group[key[0]] = value
    conn.close()

    return jsonify(group), 200


# DELETE: Deleting a group
@app.route(URI_FOR_ALL_GROUPS + '/<int:id>', methods=['DELETE'])
def delete_group(id):
    # Method to delete a single group
    conn = create_connection()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    query = ("DELETE FROM groups WHERE group_id = %d" % id)
    cursor.execute(query)
    conn.commit()

    return jsonify('Group Deleted'), 200

@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
  response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Authorization')
  response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS')
  return response


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is the html and script code I use to delete a group

```
<tbody ng-repeat = "groups in allGroups">
            <tr ng-repeat = "item in groups">
                <td ng-bind = "item.group_id"></td>
                <td ng-bind = "item.group_name"></td>
                <td ng-bind = "item.team_a"></td>
                <td ng-bind = "item.team_b"></td>
                <td ng-bind = "item.team_c"></td>
                <td ng-bind = "item.team_d"></td>
                <td><button ng-click="">Select Group</button></td>
                <td><button ng-click = "deleteGroup(item.group_id)">Delete Group</button></td>

$scope.deleteGroup = function(id)
        {
            $http({
                method: "DELETE",
                url: ("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/groups/" + id),
            }).then(function onSuccess() {
                alert("Group has been deleted");
            }, function error() {
                alert("Something went wrong: Error No. 3");
            });
        };
```

Comment: what you get in the console after click submit>?

Comment: remove the ',' after data: $scope.form

Comment: @BartoszTermena With JavaScript, commas are legal after the last entry in an object literal.

Comment: Modify the error handler to `console.log` the error response. Ignoring the error response and alerting with "Opps" is not helpful.

Comment: VM201:1 OPTIONS http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/groups/undefined 404 (NOT FOUND)

Comment: I had an issue with CORS but I added code to my API - def after_request(response):
  response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Authorization')
  response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS')
  return response

Comment: Im getting this error in the console as well - Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/groups/undefined' from origin 'http://localhost:63342' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Comment: But my GET, POST and DELETE are working as they should

Comment: My response headers are 
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * 

Which I assumed should allow the PUT request to go through. But im getting a 404 error and the url is 127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/groups/undefined which the undefined should be an id that is passed through the form

Comment: is undefined allowed to be bound to that routing parameter? If you are expecting to receive a number in that path location of the URL, the preflight is going to see that there is no resource by that name and return a 404. That 404 is triggering your failure cascade which will manifest as an ACAO CORS exception

Comment: My intention is to have the id passed with the url for example the url api/v1/groups/1 would update the row matching that id on my database. I think my issue is i'm not correctly passing the id into the angular function from my form

Comment: @Alan ...verifying the basics first will set you well on your way to solving your problem.  Since you have control over both the client and the server, add a new parameterless route that supports PUT. Make sure it has CORS support. Now modify your xhr to send a PUT request to it. I'm betting you will get your 200.

Comment: @Alan you have a multi-layered problem at hand. You're not binding your parameter properly (as you state) and the server does not support 'undefined' in that path location, thus yielding a 404, thus cascading out as a CORS exception in the client.

Comment: Thanks you for the advice. I will try it next time I look at the program. I was just curious why my DELETE which takes an ID has no issue but PUT doesnt work. It makes me think Ive coded something wrong

Comment: @Alan Edit your code snippet to include the template for the DELETE action. The other easy,thing you can do to improve your information is to change the model bound to the update action to pass in `update`. Then inspect it at runtime to see if it is binding into your "updateGroups" call. It could just be a property typo, but I can't tell without more context.

Comment: @Alan ...did that suggestion fix your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That issue is triggered server-side.

Your Api is not allowing "undefined" to bind to your routing parameter. Try creating a vanilla "Foo" service, which just returns a 200. When you call it, I'm betting your PUT to that service goes through just fine.

After you can verify that your service layer supports HTTP PUT requests, you can focus in on why your client is not binding the parameter to the desired call correctly.

During that inspection of the client, you might want to set a breakpoint in your controller at the point `update` gets assigned its group_id. You did not provide it in your sample.

---

Now that you have provided more context, the client side issue appears to be related to you switching model references from `item` in your `deleteGroup` block to using `update` in your `updateGroups` block. If you change your 'update' references to instead refer to `item` I am confident you will change your results. For this to work for you though, you have to push the 'update form into the repeater so that it can gain access to the appropriate group item which is being updated. At that point, I believe you will have your service call parameterizing correctly. Your view may not be what you want it to be after this change, but you'll have to resolve that separately.  To be clear, this is not the way I write angular code, so I'm not putting it out as an advisable approach to solving your problem (especially since I don't know what problem you are trying to solve) but given the code you have provided, I believe that to be the crux of your binding problem.

Comment: Ive added my restful API to my question

Comment: I added my DELETE $scope and my table which display each group in the database and has a button which when clicked, passed the id to the scope

Comment: @Alan I see. The nature of your issue is exactly as I suspected. `undefined` cannot bind to an int on the server, thus there is no matching route template for your request.  Server executes the expected behavior, which is to say no resource exists at your locator, which is a 404. Since the request is a PUT, there is a CORS preflight which expects to verify that the resource locator is valid. That 404 manifests as a CORS exception in your browser. *Why* you are sending undefined is a separate layer of the issue.

Comment: @Alan The *why* is that your binding variable to your updateGroups call is incorrect. In your sample for delete, you bind it to `item` but you attempt to bind `updateGroups` to a scoped `update` variable, but you used `item` in your ng-repeat. Try changing that property reference to bind to `item.group_id` and I bet you'll change your results.

Comment: I changed it to updateGroups(item.group_id) and still encounter the same issue with it being undefined. I think I will explore other methods on how best to allow users to update groups. I feel my form isnt working as it should do.

Im thankful for the help, I feel I may have over-complicated it for myself

Comment: @Alan I notice that you have your update form template called out independently from your delete template. If you were to put your `update` button alongside that delete button and parameterized it similarly, what is your I'd bound to inside updateGroups?

Comment: @Alan ok.I can see your problem a little better now and that structure does not look like it is going to get you where you want to go.Your `delete` action is contextualized to be inside the ng-repeat. Actions undertaken within that scope (the repeater) will have access to an `item` reference.But your update form is outside the repeater.It has no reference to the group itself because you can think of `ng-repeat` as a foreach loop,`item` as your cursor, and `allGroups` as your set.Put your update form inside your repeater and make sure you refer to it as `item`.Let me know if that changes output

Comment: Adding my update form into the repeater caused additional issues with selecting a group, no longer populating the form. Im gonna go back to the drawing board and search for alternative methods to updating a group. Again thanks for the help

Comment: @Alan I,see you have a "Select Group" labeled button inside your repeater, but you don't have the button wired in to do anything.